# File upload using AJAX instead of form submission

Tags: java, jsf-2, richfaces

I am trying to upload a file,  using rich:fileUpload control, I am able to do so successfully too. The only problem I am facing here, is when I click on the upload button in the file upload control, the page gets submitted, which I am trying to avoid.

What I am trying to do, is as soon as the upload button is clicked, the listener is called which does necessary backend operations. And the section is refreshed where the picture is to be displayed. Everything is running fine but I want to do file uploading via AJAX.

I am using Richfaces 4.1

```
<rich:fileUpload addLabel="Add photo" clearAllLabel="Clear All" clearLabel="Clear"
    deleteLabel="Remove" doneLabel="Upload successful!"
    uploadLabel="Upload profile pic"
    fileUploadListener="#{studentProfile.fileUploadListener}"
    acceptedTypes="jpg, gif, png, bmp" noDuplicate="true" immediateUpload="false">
    <!-- <a4j:ajax event="uploadcomplete" render="validationButton"/> -->
    <!-- <a4j:ajax event="clear" listener="#{uploadBean.doClearFilesList}" render="validationButton"/> -->
            <a4j:ajax event="uploadcomplete" render="profilepic" immediate="true" />
</rich:fileUpload>



<a4j:outputPanel ajaxRendered="true" id="profilepic">
        <rich:panel header="Profile Picture" style="width: 100px;height: 100px">
    <h:graphicImage url="#{studentProfile.profilePictureURL}" width="100" height="100" />
        </rich:panel>
</a4j:outputPanel>
```

Comment: With real AJAX is not posible. But with iframe, yes!

Comment: Can you be little more descriptive?

Answer (score 0):

use h:commandlink too target the iframe name then on<click action call a string method that return the url too th
rich faces page this well only reload th rich face page and not the main page....